# Question concerning ヶ in 一ヶ月

Tags: grammar, meaning, words, usage, kanji

一箇月 is an outdated version of 一ヶ月

The ヶ in this case is not the katakana ケ but a shorthand for the kanji: 箇 **and** therefore does not produce the "ke" sound.

I got this idea because ヶ kind of looks like the bamboo radical in the top left. Is my assumption correct? Are there other characters that have the same function as ヶ? What are these **shorthands** called?

Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_ke

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The (Chinese) abbreviated form of the kanji is 个. The handwritten form of this looks rather like ケ, so ケ came to be used in Japanese.